# which one is better and Why? accessing parent through scope hierarchy or sharing using a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My application has a parent controller calling a rest service and getting a response Obj.The Response Obj is been used by many other controllers down the line.which of these ways are better to share the response obj with the child controllers.

1. Directly accessing through the scope hierarchy.
2. binding the responseobj with a service property and the service is
       injected to all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say option 2.

Best option is to binding the Responseobject to a Service and inject in to your all controllers.

Comment: When i am having a second asynchronous rest call I need to update the responseobj with the new response and have to intimate all the controllers using the Service that its been updated.To acheive this i am putting a watch in the responseobj in parent controller and inside watch the new value is been broadcasted to all other child controllers.is this the right way

Comment: If you are not using all your controllers at the same time, then I would say using the option 2 will update all your controllers. When you update your service with the updated restcall, it will be available for all your controllers as well.

Comment: let me clarify. the service hold the 1st-rest-call-responsedata and a child controller gets the value and the view is rendered fine.

then comes a 2nd-rest-call-responsedata but the view is still displaying the previous data.

how can we handle this?

Comment: OK. Now I got the clear picture. There are different ways you can handle these kind of scenarios. Best option is have one controller for single page application which is easy to manage and process data. If you really need multiple controllers then you need to handle through the pub / sub Design Pattern. You can get more details on [Communicating in AngularJS with the Pub/Sub Design Pattern - See more at:] (http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/04/29/hailing-all-frequencies-communicating-in-angularjs-with-the-pubsub-design-pattern/#sthash.UIUNGSNu.dpuf)